# Making a get request from an iOS app to a MEVN app

Tags: ios, express, vue.js, get, vue-router

I've built a Vuejs SPA with an Express/Node backend. All works fine. I'm now starting to build an iOS app that can use the same Express/Node backend.

From iOS (Xcode), when I make a post request, say to login a user, all works fine. I pass my login credentials using Alamofire and get my JWT token back no sweat.

However, whenever I try to make any get requests (from iOS) to my backend, I get the following response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><link rel="shortcut icon" type=image/x-icon href=/static/favicon.ico><link rel=apple-touch-icon href=/static/ios.png><meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-capable content=yes><meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style content=white><script src=https://js.stripe.com/v3/ ></script><BUNCH OF OTHER STUFF HERE></body></html>
```

The same route works fine in the SPA.

I'm lost. I'm probably making some kind of rookie mistake. If I change the express route to a post route, redeploy, and change the alamofire request to post, it works fine. I'm guessing this has something to do with Vue or Vue Router. If anyone knows a simple fix to allow my get requests to make it through to the backend, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into this issue...It had to do with the [connect-history-api-fallback](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback) middleware.

Once I added 'Accept', 'application/json' to the request header, I was good to go.

https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback/blob/master/examples/static-files-and-index-rewrite/assets/js/index.js#L4